# content type issue with SOAP::Lite

Tags: wcf, web-services, perl, client

When I'm trying connect to server I got below error msg:

> Cannot process the message because the
>   content type 'text/xml' was not the
>   expected type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8'

I read it connect to server (implemented in WCF), but can I fix it also with my side (the client) implemented in Perl using the [SOAP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP%3a%3aLite) module?

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that client expects the response from Webservice using message version Soap 1.1 and thus, expecting content-type of the message to be 'text/xml'. However, it's sending the messages to the service endpoint using Soap 1.2 message version.

If perl/Soap Lite supports Soap 1.2, it can communicate with WCF on this endpoint.

HTH,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I am still struggling to get my perl application to consume a WCF based web service but I was able to get past the error you are referrign to in your post.

To change the content type use this command.

```
$SOAP::Constants::DEFAULT_HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/soap+xml';
```